# Javascript "ch.match is not a function"

Tags: javascript, json, function

So I have two function. I'll post them both here:

```
//A
var ltrToNato = function(ch) {
  var x = ch
  var nato =
    ('{"A": "Alpha", "B": "Bravo", "C": "Charlie", "D": "Delta", "E": "Echo", "F": "Foxtrot", "G": "Golf", "H": "Hotel", "I": "India", "J": "Juliet", "K": "Kilo",\
  "L": "Lima", "M": "Mike", "N": "November", "O": "Oscar", "P": "Papa", "Q": "Quebec", "R": "Romeo", "S": "Sierra", "T": "Tango", "U": "Uniform", "V": "Victor",\
  "W": "Whiskey", "X": "X-Ray", "Y": "Yankee", "Z": "Zulu", "0" : "Zero", "1" : "One", "2" : "Two", "3" : "Three", "4" : "Four", "5" : "Five", "6" : "Six",\
   "7" : "Seven", "8" : "Eight", "9" : "Niner"}')
  var natoLower = nato.toLowerCase()
  var natoAlpha = JSON.parse(nato)
  var natoAlphaLower = JSON.parse(natoLower)
  if (ch >= "A" && ch <= "Z")
    return natoAlpha[ch]
  else if (ch >= "a" && ch <= "z")
    return (natoAlphaLower[ch])
  else if (x = x.match(/[0-9]/g))
    return natoAlpha[ch]
  else
    return x
}

//B
var wordToNato1 = function(str) {
  var s = ""
  for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
    s + ltrToNato(i)
  }
}
```

With the first function, I want to take any letter or number and return its Nato form. So `"A"` would be `Alpha` and `"9"` would be `Niner` and so on. The `ltrToNato` function woulds perfectly fine. No problems.

With the second function I want to be able to take a string and do the same thing with every character. So for example, `wordToNato("ABC123")` would be `"Alpha Bravo Charlie One Two Three"`. This is where something goes wrong. Everytime I try to run this in the console by calling `wordToNato` it brings the error message

> ch.match is not a function

So I have no idea what is going wrong...Please help

Comment: You never call `ch.match`, where is that error message coming from? Also, you are doing `x = x.match(/[0-9]/g)` which is...a bit odd. Are you sure you want to do assignment or did you mean to do a comparison?

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something here ?

You want to convert letter to string by your mapped words.

So, simply split the input to characters. Then map them to your words and join all together with a single space.

```js
var MAP ={A:"Alpha",B:"Bravo",C:"Charlie",D:"Delta",E:"Echo",F:"Foxtrot",G:"Golf",H:"Hotel",I:"India",J:"Juliet",K:"Kilo",L:"Lima",M:"Mike",N:"November",O:"Oscar",P:"Papa",Q:"Quebec",R:"Romeo",S:"Sierra",T:"Tango",U:"Uniform",V:"Victor",W:"Whiskey",X:"X-Ray",Y:"Yankee",Z:"Zulu",0:"Zero",1:"One",2:"Two",3:"Three",4:"Four",5:"Five",6:"Six",7:"Seven",8:"Eight",9:"Niner"};


function strToNato(str){
    return str.toUpperCase().split('').map(l => MAP[l] || l).join(' ');
}

console.log(strToNato('ABC123'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the character at the position, not the value of the loop index:

```
s + ltrToNato( str.charAt( i ) )
```

Additionally, your loop is going past the end of the string. You should use `<` instead of `<=`

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
```

Your program appears to have many other errors, but this answers this specific question.

Answer (score 0):

A couple changes:

1. To answer your question, the call to *ltrToNato* is being passed an integer - the value of *i*. Utilize the character at the index, instead of the index, and add the value returned from *ltrToNato* to the cumulator variable *s* (use the [+=](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) operator to simplify the concatenation):

   `s += ltrToNato(str[i]);`

   You could also use [charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) instead of indexing into the string like an array.
2. The *for* loop should not iterate through the length, since *i* starts at 0. Either make the middle expression go to one less than the length `i <= str.length-1` or use a less than comparison: `i < str.length`.

   Instead of using a *for* statement, you could invoke [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on *str*:

   `return Array.prototype.reduce.call(str,function(returnVal,character) {
     return returnVal + ltrToNato(character);
   });`

   That way you don't have to worry about the for loop bookkeeping. Read more about functional programming [here](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/).
3. return the string after adding to var *s* at the end of *wordToNato1*:

   `return s;`
4. The check of `x.match()` will return an array or null, so your conditional expression `else if (x = x.match(/[0-9]/g))` will *assign* the value of [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to x, overwriting it with the new value, which could get used in the final *else* block (i.e. `return x`).

See these changes applied in the example below:

```js
var ltrToNato = function(ch) {
  var x = ch
  var nato =
    ('{"A": "Alpha", "B": "Bravo", "C": "Charlie", "D": "Delta", "E": "Echo", "F": "Foxtrot", "G": "Golf", "H": "Hotel", "I": "India", "J": "Juliet", "K": "Kilo",\
  "L": "Lima", "M": "Mike", "N": "November", "O": "Oscar", "P": "Papa", "Q": "Quebec", "R": "Romeo", "S": "Sierra", "T": "Tango", "U": "Uniform", "V": "Victor",\
  "W": "Whiskey", "X": "X-Ray", "Y": "Yankee", "Z": "Zulu", "0" : "Zero", "1" : "One", "2" : "Two", "3" : "Three", "4" : "Four", "5" : "Five", "6" : "Six",\
   "7" : "Seven", "8" : "Eight", "9" : "Niner"}')
  var natoLower = nato.toLowerCase()
  var natoAlpha = JSON.parse(nato)
  var natoAlphaLower = JSON.parse(natoLower)
  if (ch >= "A" && ch <= "Z")
    return natoAlpha[ch]
  else if (ch >= "a" && ch <= "z")
    return (natoAlphaLower[ch])
  else if (x.match(/[0-9]/g))
    return natoAlpha[ch]
  else
    return x
}

//B
var wordToNato1 = function(str) {
  var s = ""
  for (var i = 0; i <= str.length-1; i++) {
    s += ltrToNato(str[i])
  }
  return s;
}
console.log('nato: '+wordToNato1("ABC123"));
```